# What is the access specifier of jsp implementation class ?

Tags: jsp

I wanted to know access specifier of jsp implementation class that gets created after translation of jsp source page ? is it final/static/abstract or private ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access specifier is `public final` for jsp implemented  class that gets created after translation of jsp source page.

If you are using `eclipse` you can see that generated file in  `workspace\metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\ProjectName\org\apache\jsp`.

See below image for reference

[image: Generated JSP]